# How to prevent getting nauseated during workouts?

Tags: workout, nausea

Last night at the gym, I apparently pushed myself a little too hard, and I threw up all over the shower.  I'd rather not do that again, so:

- What causes this?
- What can I do to increase how much work I can do without throwing up?

Comment: This question is quite old, but here are some good tips as well. http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-Throwing-up-when-Exercising

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a Wikipedia article about [Exercise-induced nausea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exercise_induced_nausea) where they suggest two possible causes: endorphins and too much water. [There has also been a study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11237347?dopt=Abstract) that showed that exercising shortly after eating is likely to cause this. Which is supported by this article about "[Nausea during a strength training workout](http://skinnybulkup.com/exercise-induced-nausea/)" that suggests three common factors that contribute to workout nausea:

> - Too much food or water in the stomach, which is likely the case just
>     after eating or drinking too much
>     water (see above)
> - High or maximum heart rate and uncontrolled breathing, which elevates
>     the blood pressure to heights that can
>     give a 'sick to the stomach' feeling.
> - Bending over during a period of maximum heart rate, while inhaling.
>     This messes with the muscle that
>     closes off the top of the stomach and
>     fails under such strains.

They also provide several tips to prevent it:

> - Get enough rest between sets with very high heart rates
> - Don't bend over to adjust the weights, this avoids compressing the
>     stomach
> - Drink the bare minimum amount of water that you feel you need (not too
>     much, but also not too little)
> - Don't drink carbonated drinks!

Furthermore, resist the urge to gulp water when you're thirsty. Drink the water in sips and pause for a moment to let your body absorb. The thirst satisfaction of your brain doesn't respond instantaneously.

Getting more exercised or in better shape won't help, because you'll always have a maximum and if you push for it, you'll reach it.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. If I dont feel sick I know I didnt work hard enough. But, I also dont have any food or drink a couple hours before a workout.

Answer (score 3):

I had a particularly effective HIT weight training workout today, and after two sets I was so gassed and queasy that I had to lay down on the bench for a few minutes to let everything settle down. I hadn't just eaten or drank, and while my heart was racing I don't think it was *that* high and my breathing was still under control (although certainly I was short of breath). I recalled a section addressing this from the [Body By Science Question and Answer Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/145057341X) (p. 237-240), and from that I'd like to add one more potential cause to @Ivo's list.

> The nausea that one feels is a result
>   of burning so much glycogen out of the
>   muscles that the body attempts to
>   continue muscular contraction by
>   manufacturing more glucose out of the
>   lactic acid that has been building up
>   within the muscle.

<*Long chemical process explanation*>

> The upshot of this complicated
>   biochemical process is that when a
>   trainee runs out of glycogen in his
>   working muscles and his body liberates
>   lactate into his bloodstream, his pH
>   levels drop off markedly, producing a
>   strong lactic acidosis and feelings of
>   nausea.

This effect causes a drop in blood pressure (often perceived as light-headedness), and the inadequate blood flow to the abdomen produces the feeling of nausea.

A couple ways to combat this feeling:

- Increase rest time between sets to allow the body to keep up with the demands that are being placed on it
- Consume a bit of sugar immediately upon feeling the symptoms (or beforehand if you are certain that this will be a problem).